# I am receiving an error when executing python <function personAge at 0x101fe6050> instead of the value

Tags: python

I am trying to complete this program for a computer science class, but I am stuck on this error

Hello Tristan Wiener. You are function personAge at 0x101fe6050 years old.

Why am I getting  instead of te age?

```
`#This program calculates a users age while collecting the user's 
 #birth year, the user's first and last name, the current year
 #and whether the user has had their birthday yet.

 firstName = raw_input("Please enter your first name")#Get the first name
 lastName = raw_input("Please enter your last name")#Get the last name
 birthYear = int(input("What is your birth year?"))#Get the birth year
 currentYear = int(input("What is the current year?"))#Get the current year

birthdayYet = raw_input("Have you had your birthday yet? [1 for yes/2 for no]")
#Ask if the user has had their birthday
age = 0


def fullName (firstName, lastName):
   outStr = firstName +" "+lastName 
   return outStr

def personAge(birthYear, currentYear, birthdayYet):
   if birthdayYet == 1:
       print(currentYear - birthYear)

   if birthdayYet == 2:
      age = currentYear - birthYear - 1
      return str(age)

def printMsg(personName,personAge):
   return ("Hello" + " " + str(personName) + "." + " " + "You are" + " " + str(personAge) + " " + "years old.")

personName = fullName(firstName, lastName)
userAge = personAge(birthYear, currentYear, birthdayYet)
finalMsg = printMsg(personName, personAge)

print finalMsg`
```

Comment: You have to call the function with arguments or use the right variable name,

Comment: That is not an error. That is the string representation of a function object.

Answer (score 0):

Replace …

```
finalMsg = printMsg(personName, personAge)
```

… with …

```
finalMsg = printMsg(personName, userAge)
```

Remember `personAge` is a function not a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
finalMsg = printMsg(personName, personAge)
```

Should be

```
finalMsg = printMsg(personName, userAge)
```

`personAge` is the function you are using to get the persons age. `userAge` is the persons actual age.